# tailwindcss watch mode doesn't work in bash script

Tags: bash, tailwind-css

My `dev.sh` looks like this. When I run `./dev.sh`, the app.css wouldn't be created.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tailwindcss -i src/tailwind.css -o dist/app.css -w &
```

However, any of the following works:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# removed the ampersand
tailwindcss -i src/tailwind.css -o dist/app.css -w
```

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# but doesn't watch
tailwindcss -i src/tailwind.css -o dist/app.css &
```

or run it directly:

```bash
$ tailwindcss -i src/tailwind.css -o dist/app.css -w &
```

Comment: I don't really understand this -- is there a reason why you need the `&` to be there?

Comment: Yes, I need to run other commands after it. I cannot let the watch mode block my script.

Comment: Then what you have should work perfectly. Can you attatch the command you're running afterwards?

Comment: @LeoDog896 what did you mean by `should work perfectly`? Did you try yourself before saying it? And why does what command I run afterwards matter?